# How to Export User Defined Library in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I've created a rather large library:

```
DataStructures.h :
       Stack.h :
           Stack.c
       LinkedList.h :
           LinkedList.c
       HashTable.h :
           HashTable.c 
       etc...
```

How would I export this library so others can use them? Would they have to link the .c together with their main?

Comment: Are you asking how to compile into a shared lib? You'd need to supply your 3rd party the shared lib or static lib and header files.

Comment: @spartygw Ok, I thought I could get away with not sending the header files; so how would compile all these files and in use them in a different project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile your .c files into a library and distribute the library and headers together.

There are two types of library; dynamic (ending in `.so` on Linux) and static (ending in `.a` on Linux).

I believe static libs end in .lib on Windows and dynamic libs end in .dll over there, but I'm not a windows dev.

Macs can have both `.so` and `.dylib` files, depending on your tool chain.

On Linux, the general way to make a static lib is with the tools `ar` and `ranlib`.  Assuming your Makefile has a list of object files called OBJS,

```
mylibrary.a: $(OBJS)
        ar -ru $@ $(OBJS)
        ranlib $@
```

Creating a shared library is similar, but instead of `ar` and `ranlib`, you usually use `gcc -shared`, and you must compile the object files for "position independent code", ie add `-fPIC` to your CFLAGS.

Once you have the library and the header files, place the headers in a directory called "include" and the library in a directory called "lib".  Archive these two directories up (eg with tar or zip) and send them to whoever is using them.

Note that they will need the same kind of computer, operating system version, compiler, etc as you.  This is why C library code is most frequently shared in source code format.